# T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error on line 5

Tags: php

I am getting this error when I parse the following code. I also tried add `\` to some of the arrays but didn't get it...

```
<?php

function convert($fromc, $toc, $otext) {
    $raavi = array("~", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "+", "`", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "_", "=", "ਥ", "ੱ", "ਓ", "੍ਰ", "ਠ", "ੈ", "ੂ", "ੀ", "ੌ", "ਫ", "{", "}", "।", "ਤ", "ੱ", "ੲ", "ਰ", "ਟ", "ੇ", "ੁ", "ਿ", "ੋ", "ਪ", ".", "॥", "\\", "ੳ", "ੰ", "ਧ", "ਾਂ", "ਘ", "੍ਹ", "ਝ", "ਖ", "਼", ":", "\"", "ਅ", "ਸ", "ਦ", "ਾ", "ਗ", "ਹ", "ਜ", "ਕ", "ਲ", ";", "'", "ਢ", "ਯ", "ਛ", "ੜ", "ਭ", "ਂ", "ੰ", ",", ">", "?", "ਡ", "ਣ", "ਚ", "ਵ", "ਬ", "ਨ", "ਮ", ",", "।", "/", "ੴ", "॥", "#", "੍ਰ", "•", "।", "ੴ", "ੴ", "☬", "ਸ਼", "ਖ਼", "ਗ਼", "ਜ਼", "ਫ਼", "੍ਯ", "#", "॥", "ਲ਼", "੧", "੨");
    $drchatrik = array("~", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "+", "`", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-", "=", "Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O," "P", "{", "}", "|", "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p", "[", "]", "\\", "A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", ":", "\"", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", ";", "'", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", ",", ">", "?", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ",", ".", "/", "¡", "«", "¬", "R", "•", "»", "Ã", "Å", "Ç", "È", "É", "Ê", "Ë", "Ì", "Î", "Ñ", "Ò", "Ü", "ñ", "ò");
    $combine = array_combine($$fromc, $$toc);
    $converted = strtr($otext, $combine);
}

?>
```

Plz help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a misplaced comma after the `"O"` on line 5.